# Using Another js files class name in render function of another js file

Tags: reactjs, react-component

I have two files App.js and MenuComponent.js . MenuComponent has a Menu class I want to use that class inside App.js file's render function return statement.

```
render(){
return(
<div> Arun </div>
<Menu />
);
}
```

I can't able to use like this if I use only the Menu tag it works

Answer (score 0):

You need to return a single child or an array of children

e.g.:

```
return (
  <>
    <div> Arun </div>
    <Menu />
  </>
);
```

or the equivalent

```
return (
  <React.Fragment>
    <div> Arun </div>
    <Menu />
  </React.Fragment>
);
```

or with an array of children

```
return [
  <div key="unique-key-1"> Arun </div>,
  <Menu key="unique-key-2" />
];
```